# How can i reduce the size of node_modules folder?

Tags: laravel, npm

I've done the application creation using laravel, every time I want to create a front end template using laravel mix, or tailwind, the file should not be too big (less than 100mb). When I run npm install, my development files get really big. I have done many ways that are scattered on the internet, but what is an efficient way to reduce the size of node_modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a laravel web app, you do not need to upload the `node_modules` to any server to successfully run your app, all you need is to upload the compiled `css` and `js` files which are typically located within the public folder. The `node_modules` folder is only useful when you are in development. And you said you are done with the app which means you are not going to develop soon so you can delete the `node_modules` folder and your app will be just fine.

And later if you want to add more features, you can just run `npm i` to install all the packages back which will bring back the `node_modules` folder.

Hope this helps, if you really want to reduce the size of `node_modules` due to your disk limitation then all I can say is use fewer packages or choose other packages that have fewer dependencies.

Comment: I was unaware of this. I suppose you always learn something unexpected here.